# MYSQL Random Row/Ordering question

Tags: sql, mysql, random

I am trying to select the three rows that have the highest scores. Obviously I can use a simple things such as:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable ORDER BY myscore DESC LIMIT 3;
```

But what I also want is an easy way for this to return only one of these three rows randomly. Normally I just do an ORDER BY rand(), but what is the cleanest way to add the constraint that it has to be a random one from only the top 3 scored rows?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT * FROM myTable ORDER BY myscore DESC LIMIT 3
) Top3
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1;
```